# Rubyで JSON in Array をファイルから読み込みたい

Tags: ruby, json

Rubyでjsonファイルの中に以下の様な形でデータが入っているときに、Hash in Array として変数に取り込みたいです。

`JSON.load`で読むと`nilClass`として読まれてしまい、`read`で読むと`String`になってしまい、うまくいかずに困っています。いい読み込み方はありませんか？

**対象のJSONファイル (hoge.json)**

```js
[
  {
    "name": "hoge",
    "age": 18
  },
  {
    "name": "hoge",
    "age": 18
  },
...
]
```

Comment: うまく行かなかったときの実際のコードを書くと回答しやすそうです

Comment: 「`JSON.load` で読むと `nilClass` として読まれてしまい」ってもしかして、`load` の引数にファイル名を渡していませんかね。irb上で `data = JSON.load('hoge.json')` のようにすると、 _例外が出た後に_ `data` に `nil` が返されたように見えるはず。

Answer (score 1):

一度ファイルの内容を文字列として読み込んでからparseするといいと思います

```
require 'json'

json = File.read('hoge.json')
JSON.parse(json)
```

`JSON.load` で読み込む場合このような感じでFileのようにIOのようなオブジェクトを渡すとよいです

```
require 'json'

File.open('hoge.json') { |f| JSON.load(f) }
```